# Why isn't onSaveInstanceState called for second activity?

Tags: android

I have created two activities: MainActivity and ActivityTwo. If I click a button on the Main, it launches Two, like below. I have added codes to track `onSaveInstanceState` and `onDestroy`. The output was like the following:

- I click the button to start Two
- main: saveinstance
- I click the back button to return to Main
- two: onDestroy
- I click the back button again to exit the app
- main: saveinstance

So, onSaveInstanceState is not called for Two, and onDestroy is not called for Main. Why is onSaveInstanceState not called for Two?

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
      val intent = Intent(this, ActivityTwo::class.java);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }

  override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)
  {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    Log.d("stack", "main: saveinstance ");
  }

  override fun onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d("stack", "main: onDestroy");
  }
```

Comment: What is the API level of your device?

Comment: @BömachtBlau Android 12 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)**

If called, this method will occur after onStop() for applications targeting platforms starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.P. For applications targeting earlier platform versions this method will occur before onStop() and there are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause().

I hope it might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your comment, you observed the unexpected behavior on an emulator running Android 12.

With the introduction of Android 12, there has been a behavior change for  [Activity.onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()):

Behavior on devices running Android 11 (corresponds to Build.VERSION_CODES.R) or lower:

> On platform versions prior to Build.VERSION_CODES.S, it finishes the current activity

Behavior on devices running Android 12+:

> Starting with platform version Build.VERSION_CODES.S, for activities that are the root activity of the task and also declare an IntentFilter with Intent#ACTION_MAIN and Intent#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER in the manifest, the current activity and its task will be moved to the back of the activity stack instead of being finished. Other activities will simply be finished